# How to solve Cauchy problem if equation is not linear and there is no $t$ argument?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, cauchy-problem

Given the ODE $x'=3x^{2/3}$ with the initial condition $x(0)=0$, I tried to use an integration multiplicator method, but my solution is incorrect, I assume it's related to equation not being linear. As there are no $t$ argument, I cannot transform equation into $t(x)$ form or can I? Or maybe there is altogether different method how to solve this problem?

Comment: Are you sure is $x'=3x^{\frac{2}{3}}=0$?

Comment: Usually you'd separate the variables. However, in this case the ODE fails the uniqueness condition of Cauchy-Lipschitz theorem, so you must *also* account for multiple solutions, of which it turns out there are uncountably many.

Comment: It's an autonomous equation you can integrate easily you don't need an integrating factor.

Comment: Note that $x'+x=0$ is linear allthough the t variable is not present.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you mean $x'-3x^{2/3} = 0 \iff x' = 3x^{2/3}$, in which case you integrate both sides:
$$
\frac{dx}{dt} = 3x^{2/3} \iff \int dt = \int \frac{dx}{3x^{2/3}}
$$
can you finish?

Comment: $t=x^{\frac{1}{3}} \Rightarrow x(t)=t^3$, but I don't understand the logic behind it, isn't it possible to do it by integration multiplicator, if not, why? Previously I assumed, that you must multiply the whole expression with $e^{\int p(t) dt}$.

Comment: @user that formula works for linear equation of first order. That's not the case here. $$y'(t)+p(t)y=g(t)$$ I don't undersand the downvote.